# How to set up SQLite for Java under Ubuntu?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, ubuntu

I would like to use SQLite for some database functionality with a Java program I am implementing, but I don't know how to install SQLite and make it work with Java under Ubuntu.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need [a JDBC driver for SQLite](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) in order to access it from your java app.

Then, to set up sqlite under ubuntu `apt-get install cl-sql-sqlite3 sqlitebrowser`.

Sqlite browser is quite practical. Nevertheless, I would suggest you consider that sqlite is not the easiest way to deploy a java database. You should have a look at [javadb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/index.html).

Comment: your link to JDBC driver for SQLite is dead ( 20210305123557 )

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomment [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/).

> **What is SQLJet**
>
> SQLJet is an independent pure Java implementation of a
> popular SQLite database management system. SQLJet is a software
> library that provides API that enables Java application to read and
> modify SQLite databases.

Check out their [tutorial](http://sqljet.com/tutorial.html).

To install, just download the Library and add it to your classpath.